# MySQL duplicate result with join

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have a table *order_status_history* in which is stored one row for every order status change and I want to get the last entry for a determined order status.

Tables involved (simplified):

```
orders
| id     | 
| 1      |  

order_products
| id     | order_id | productid | quantity| 
| 1      | 1        | 1         | 1       | 
| 2      | 1        | 1         | 2       | 
| 3      | 1        | 1         | 2       | 
| 4      | 1        | 1         | 10      |  

order_status_history
| id     | order_id | order_status_id | updatedat              | 
| 1      | 1        | 1               | 2017-05-18 18:45:50    | 
| 2      | 1        | 2               | 2017-05-19 18:45:50    | 
| 3      | 1        | 3               | 2017-05-20 18:45:50    | 
| 4      | 1        | 2               | 2017-05-21 18:45:50    | 
| 5      | 1        | 3               | 2017-05-22 18:45:50    |
```

What I exactly need is:

If the last order status is "3" (as "4" means cancelled or anyway not more available), for each order id get only the last entry (based on updatedat column, last means most recent)

This is the query I tried, but in this case returns 2 rows for the same order id and status 3:

```sql
SELECT o.id, 
       osh.updatedat, 
       op.quantity 
FROM   orders_products op 
       LEFT JOIN order_status_history osh 
              ON osh.order_id = op.orderid 
       LEFT JOIN orders o 
              ON o.id = op.orderid 
WHERE  op.productid = 1 
       AND (SELECT osh.order_status_id 
            FROM   order_status_history osh 
            WHERE  osh.order_id = o.id 
            ORDER  BY osh.updatedat DESC 
            LIMIT  1) = 3
```

Comment: Please try to provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Modified question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that without any entry in the `orders` table, there cannot be any entry in the `orders_products` and `order_status_history` table. So, I would change the order of table join for ease of understand ability. Moreover, there is no need of `LEFT JOIN`, as we are trying to fetch rows for a specific product (hence, rows should exist in the products table), and at a specific order_status (hence, rows should exist in the status history table). So I will change all the `LEFT JOIN` in the query to `INNER JOIN`.

Now, to get the last `updatedat` row corresponding to a particular status, we will have to use a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). In this subquery, we will fetch the latest `updatedat` value for every order, when status is **3**.

Eventually, we will join this subquery result-set to the main tables appropriately, to get data corresponding to latest `updatedat` row value.

Also, it is generally a good practice to shift your `WHERE` conditions to the join `ON` clause for ease of understand-ability. Also, in future when you change from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` etc, you can easily change without worrying about unnecessary filtering happening due to `WHERE`.

---

**Try the following Query:** [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Ch3P4cJjKrx14MzjDSKbU/0)

```
SELECT 
  o.id, 
  op.quantity, 
  osh.updatedat 
FROM 
  orders AS o 
JOIN order_products AS op 
  ON op.order_id = o.id AND 
     op.productid = 1 
JOIN order_status_history AS osh 
  ON osh.order_id = o.id 
JOIN (SELECT order_id, 
             MAX(updatedat) AS max_updated_at
      FROM order_status_history 
      WHERE order_status_id = 3
      GROUP BY order_id
     ) AS dt 
  ON dt.order_id = o.id AND 
     dt.max_updated_at = osh.updatedat;
```

**Result:**

```
| id  | quantity | updatedat           |
| --- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 1        | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
| 1   | 2        | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
| 1   | 2        | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
| 1   | 10       | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
```

---

Other than `updatedat` values, if you don't need to get any other column(s) from the `order_status_history` table, you can optimize the query further by getting rid of the Join with the `order_status_history` table

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
  o.id, 
  op.quantity, 
  dt.max_updated_at AS updatedat 
FROM 
  orders AS o 
JOIN order_products AS op 
  ON op.order_id = o.id AND 
     op.productid = 1 
JOIN (SELECT order_id, 
             MAX(updatedat) AS max_updated_at
      FROM order_status_history 
      WHERE order_status_id = 3
      GROUP BY order_id
     ) AS dt 
  ON dt.order_id = o.id;
```

**Result:**

```
| id  | quantity | updatedat           |
| --- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 1        | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
| 1   | 2        | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
| 1   | 2        | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
| 1   | 10       | 2017-05-22 18:45:50 |
```